# PHP - Losing the array references out of the function (local to global)

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference

I made a small function to parse and get elements from a multidimensional array by a string written in a Unix-like path syntax.

```
function array_get($path, &$array) {
    $keys = preg_split('/[\/\\\]+/', $path, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $current = trim(array_shift($keys));
    if (is_array($array) && array_key_exists($current, $array)) {
        $path = implode("/", $keys);
        if (empty($path)) {
            // (Place the code here, see below)
            return $array[$current];
        }
        return array_get($path, $array[$current]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

So if I got a simple array like this

```
$arr = array(
    "A" => array(
        "X" => array(),
        "Y" => array(),
        "Z" => array()
    ),
    "B" => array(
        "X" => array(),
        "Y" => array(),
        "Z" => array()
    ),
    "C" => array(
        "X" => array(),
        "Y" => array(),
        "Z" => array()
    )
);
```

and I wish to fill it within some entries like these

```
$arr['A']['Z'][] = "foo";
$arr['A']['Z'][] = "bar";
```

I would do the same job using the following statements:

```
$var = array_get("A/Z", $arr);
$var[] = "foo";
$var[] = "bar";
```

*But something went wrong.*

If you try to run the code you will notice that going out of the local scope **the references to the passed array will be lost.**

If you wish to run a test, you can replace the placeholder comment line inside the function with these two code lines:

```
            $array[$current][] = "foo";
            $array[$current][] = "bar";
```

then you will see that the function would perform actually its own job.

Is there a way to **maintain the references** in output?

Comment: Yes, there's such [a way](https://eval.in/98153).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php), you can specify you want to return a reference by using the `&` character before the function name **AND** the function call.

```
<?php

function &foo(&$arr) {
  return $arr[0];
}

$a = [[]];
$b = &foo($a);
$b[0] = 'bar';
print_r($a); /* outputs [ [ 'bar' ] ] */
```

Comment: Just to expand on this answer, your calls to `array_get` must use the reference assignment. This includes it's internal recursive call.
Adding a `&` to `return foo()` will cause a syntax error, however. So you must assign it to a variable, then return the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can [return references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php).

But I find your approach really cumbersome, and it will lead to misbehaviours / maintainability / readability issues very soon.